# Generate funciton with specified bases

Tags: splines, function, basis-function, functional-data-analysis

I am trying to simulate functional data using specified bases and a set of random coefficients. For example, I can generate a function on $[0,1]$ with Fourier basis like

$$f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i sin(2i\pi x) + \sum_{j=1}^k b_j cos(2j\pi  x)$$ with the coefficients $a_i$'s and $b_j$'s.

My questions is, unlike Fourier basis which has simple forms, how can I generate a function with other bases without a simple form such as B-spline? Is there any R package can help me do so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I figured out how to do this by myself. In fact the R package `fda` has provided everything I need. For anyone who is interested you can check Chapter 4 of *Functional Data Analysis with R and MATLAB* by J.O. Ramsay, Giles Hooker, and Spencer Graves.

I will provide a short demonstration here. Suppose the we has the list of 5 coefficients from $Uniform(0,1)$ distribution, denoted as $a_1,... a_5$. We want to construct a function $f(t) = \sum_{i=1}^5 a_i \phi_i(t)$ for $0<t<1$, where $\phi_i(t)$ are B-spline bases.

First we generate the basis using

```
tempfd = create.bspline.basis(rangeval = c(0,1),nbasis = 5)
```

Then we specify the coefficients by

```
f = fd(runif(5), tempfd)
```

Suppose we need realizations at $0<t_1<...<t_{50}<1$, then

```
obs = eval.fd(f, seq(0,1,len=50))
```

will do the job.